# Getting directory Path of each item in folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filepath

I have files in a folder, and I want to return path of each file in list, and get it with JSON, now I have the list of all all my model in extension method so I have:

```
 public async Task<IList<Slider>> SliderGetList(Slider slider)
    {
        var model = await db.SlidersList.Where(x => x.IsVisible).OrderBy(x => x.Order).ToListAsync(); // there I get all list

        return model;
    }
```

Controller:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> SliderGetAll(Slider slider)
    {
        var model = await _sliderService.SliderGetList(slider);
        return new JsonCamelCaseResult(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I try these `string[] filePaths = Directory.GetDirectories("~/Content/images/slider");` this is directory I want to get path of each item there. I try these but I only get error:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\Content\images\slider'.

But I don't want to use `@:C// etc` because I upload it to server...

Thanks in advance

----------------------------Edit---------------------

I entry to folder with `var filePaths = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/slider");`, but now I don't know how to get MapPath of each item is inside there

Comment: change this "~/Content/images/slider" to "Content/images/slider".

Comment: I get these Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Content\images\slider'. @Dr.Stitch

Comment: please do this Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/slider");

Comment: Side note: you probably should not be returning server path to client because it is completely useless for client and potential security risk (information disclosure, also for most people security is not a concern at all)

Comment: First I change array for var because MapPath don't get it, and finally I do as `var filePaths = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/slider");` and now it enters to root, but now how can I read each patch of each file to return it in a list? @Dr.Stitch

Comment: I send to get it with JSON and post in Ajax View  @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: NB: `System.Web.UI.IUrlResolutionService` contains ResolveClientUrl method which returning client version of server file path. Use it to convert server path from MapPath into client path: `IUrlResolutionService urlres = sender as IUrlResolutionService; var clientPath = ResolveClientUrl(filePaths);`

Comment: it no works @TetsuyaYamamoto, I entry to folder with `var filePaths = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/slider");`, but now I don't know how to get MapPath of each item is inside there

Comment: Have you trying `String[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(filePaths);` ? If you can get this, you can proceed to `foreach (String fileName in fileEntries) { String filePath = Server.MapPath(fileName); }`. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx (AFAIK, it also returns server-side full path of all filename)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use path.combine like below

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/slider"), model.FileName);
```

Iterate through each list item and in that iteration you can use the above.
model is your model which contains list and filename is the name of each file which can be obtained through each iteration